# Should I store salt on SQL Server as varchar or varbinary and in hex?

Tags: sql, sql-server, hash, hex, salt

I'm working on implementing a hash. I intend to store the salt in a database, specifically SQL Server. The salt will be at least 32 bytes. Should the salt be in hex form or should I convert it to a string, integer, or something else?  Also, what data type should I use to store the salt: varchar, varbinary, or something else?

For security, it really doesn't matter because the salt is not a secret. But in terms of performance and maybe readability, it might.

Thank you very much.

Comment: for those wondering what salt is, http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/2010

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any cryptographic alogorithm worth its salt, (please excuse the pun) will be working on binary data. Assuming that the salts you use will be the same length you should use a `BINARY` column, if the salts are of variable length use `VARBINARY`.

The salt should be a random, or pseudo-random sequence of bytes. It should be different for each value you are hashing but can be stored in the clear.

---

Code something like this will give the values you need.

```
-- obviously, don't store a password in code,
-- this is here to enable subsequent calls.
DECLARE @password NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'Whatever';

---

DECLARE @salt BINARY(64) = CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(64);

-- There is a limit of 4000 bytes for HASHBYTES so in case the password
-- very long, truncate to 3936 bytes. If you can I'd convert the password
-- to binary before passing to SQL server.
DECLARE @passwordBytes VARBINARY(3936);
SELECT
            @passwordBytes = @passwordBytes + 
                CONVERT(BINARY(2), UNICODE(SUBSTRING([A].[B], [V].[number] + 1, 1)))
    FROM
            (SELECT CAST(@password NVARCHAR(1968)) [B]) [A]
        JOIN
            [master].[dbo].[spt_values] [V]
                ON [V].[number] < LEN([A].[B])
    WHERE
            [V].[type] = 'P';

DECLARE @hash BINARY(64) = HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', @passwordBytes + @salt);
```

Comment: @user3621633, I made the `NVARCHAR` to `VARBINARY` conversion more robust but, as I comment, better to do this outside TSQL.